# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

```
dm = torch.as_tensor(cifar100_mean, **setup)[:, None, None]
ds = torch.as_tensor(cifar100_std, **setup)[:, None, None]

def plot(tensor):
    tensor = tensor.clone().detach()
    tensor.mul_(ds).add_(dm).clamp_(0, 1) # multiply ground_truth tensor value by ds then add dm, then clamp (limit the max and min boarder)
    if tensor.shape[0] == 1: #when num_iamge=1
        return plt.imshow(tensor[0].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu()); # convert (3,32,32) to (32, 32, 3)
    else:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 5, figsize=(12, 12)) #figsize=(12, tensor.shape[0]*12)
        for idx, img in enumerate(tensor):
            axes[idx].imshow(img.permute(1, 2, 0).cpu());
```

This is the plot function that I'm using to make 20 images as subplots. (4 rows 5 columns)
and this part

```
axes[idx].imshow(img.permute(1, 2, 0).cpu());
```

is giving me an error message

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'
```

and the part `def plot(tensor):`, tensor indicates a list of CIFAR100 images. Below is how I define ground_truth.

```
from torchvision import models, datasets, transforms
toPIL = transforms.ToPILImage()
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
#variables
num_images = 20

#in data_processing.py - for reference. Do not comment in again
# validloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validset, batch_size=min(defs.batch_size, len(trainset)),
#                                           shuffle=False, drop_last=False, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=PIN_MEMORY)
# validset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=data_path, train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

#images and labels
ground_truth, labels = [], []
idx = 125 # choosen randomly ... just whatever you want
while len(labels) < num_images:
    img, label = validloader.dataset[idx]
    idx += 1
    if label not in labels:
        labels.append(torch.as_tensor((label,), device=setup['device']))
        ground_truth.append(img.to(device))

ground_truth = torch.stack(ground_truth)
labels = torch.cat(labels)
labels_print = [validloader.dataset.classes[l] for l in labels]

plot(ground_truth);
print(labels_print);
```

How can I print 20 images as subplots? Any other method is fine.

Comment: From `fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 5, figsize=(12, 12))`, `axes` will be an array of matplotlib Axes instances with shape 4x5. So when you index it with a single number, you return a slice of that 2D array. You need to either index it with a row and column, e,g. `axes[i, j]`, or flatten that array first before indexing it as you do here